# Running a .py file with selenium in docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium

I have a python script that scrapes some web information using selenium. I've build a docker image of my project:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN pip install -e .

CMD ["python", "src/project/scraper.py"]
```

I get the following error when I run it: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

The chromedriver.exe file is located in a data folder and the .py script refers to the right place (it does run locally).

Does anyone know how I would be able to run chrome in this container?
map structure is as follows:

```
|-- data
|  |--chromedriver.exe
|  |--file.csv
|-- src
|  |--project
|     |--scraper.py
|-- Dockerfile
|-- requirements.txt
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me share what has worked for me in the past.

**Try installing chrome, chromedriver, and the PATH from within the DockerFile.**

---

Note:

- Using Python 3.8. You can try changing it to 3.7 and see if it works for you.
- NOT configured for multi-stage builds.

  - i.e. You may want to remove "FROM python:3.7-slim" before appending your part at the end.

```
FROM python:3.8 AS builder

RUN apt-get update; apt-get clean

# Install chrome dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y x11vnc xvfb fluxbox wget wmctrl unzip

# Set up the Chrome PPA
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

# Update the package list and install chrome
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Set up Chromedriver Environment variables
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 87.0.4280.88
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /chromedriver
RUN mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
RUN unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Put Chromedriver into the PATH
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
# Make sure we use the virtualenv:
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

...
<YOUR_DOCKERFILE_PARTS>
```

As of today (Jan 25th, 2021), I can check the [latest stable version (released Jan 19th, 2021)](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/01/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_19.html) of google chrome is 88.0.4324.96. So if the above don't work, try changing the [Chromedriver version](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) so that it matches with the installed chrome browser.

Comment: Can't you make use of Selenium's official docker file that's already available at ```selenium/standalone-chrome```?

Answer (score 1):

I am expecting you are using Linux containers in Docker, since python:3.7-slim is a Linux image. You cannot execute Windows binaries (.exe) files in Linux. Therefore you need to install chromedriver on Linux: [How to Setup Selenium with ChromeDriver on Ubuntu 18.04 & 16.04](https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/)

Your Dockerfile should look something like this

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y unzip xvfb libxi6 libgconf-2-4 && \
    apt-get install default-jdk && \
    curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add && \
   echo "deb [arch=amd64]  http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
   apt-get -y update && \
   wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
   unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
   mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver && \
   chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver && \
   chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver    

WORKDIR /

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN pip install -e .

CMD ["python", "src/project/scraper.py"]
```